# keyboard status leds not working

Tags: xorg

Running Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

The status leds are not working correctly on my new keyboard under Ubuntu. Pressing Caps Lock and Num Lock do not cause the leds to turn on/off to reflect their status. Rather I have a num lock led stuck on, and a caps lock led that never turns on. The actual function of the caps lock and num lock is unaffected though, just the leds not working.

I am able to use ¨setleds¨ to turn the leds on an off from a console session, so I don´t think there's any hardware problem. Also the keyboard does not have the same problem under windows 7.

Anyone have any solutions?

thanks!

The keyboard in question is a Monoprice mechanical gaming keyboard:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0081TQ83K/

http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=114&cp_id=11401&cs_id=1140102&p_id=9181&seq=1&format=2

Which itself seems to be an own branded Qpad MK-85

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar keyboard (MaxKeyboard Nighthawk X8, looks identical to yours), and the following terminal command worked for me:

```
sudo kbd_mode -u
```

This should fix the NumLock LED issue.  The CapsLock issue still eludes me, and I haven't been able to locate much regarding that myself.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the same problem on Linux Mint 17.1 with the same Nighthawk x8 keyboard. Running this command give me the same result.